# Redirect depending of the UserID

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

so i have this login page

```
<?php
    require("common.php"); 
    $submitted_username = '';
    if(!empty($_POST))
    {
        $query = "
            SELECT
                id,
                username,
                password,
                salt,
                email
            FROM users
            WHERE
                username = :username
        ";
        $query_params = array(
            ':username' => $_POST['username']
        );

        try
        {
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
        }
        $login_ok = false;
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        if($row)
        {
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']);
            for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++)
            {
                $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']);
            }

            if($check_password === $row['password'])
            {
                $login_ok = true;
            }
        }
        if($login_ok)
        {
            unset($row['salt']);
            unset($row['password']);
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row;
            header("Location: private.php");
            die("Redirecting to: private.php");
        }
        else
        {
            print("Login Failed.");
            $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        }
    }

?>
<h1>Login</h1>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    Username:<br />
    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $submitted_username; ?>" />
    <br /><br />
    Password:<br />
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Session(common.php)

```
<?php

    // These variables define the connection information for your MySQL database
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbname = "phplogin";


    $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');
    try
    {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array)
        {
            foreach($array as &$value)
            {
                if(is_array($value))
                {
                    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value);
                }
                else
                {
                    $value = stripslashes($value);
                }
            }
        }

        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST);
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET);
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE);
    }

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    session_start();
?>
```

what i wanted to do is when the user who login has the "id" of "5" it will be redirected to another page different from the stated in the code which is private.php. could i redirect it to another page if it finds out that the "id" is equal to five. it like sort of admin page.

Comment: how about using if condition in  if($login_ok) block .. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it. Try this where you have written

```
 if($login_ok)
        {
            unset($row['salt']);
            unset($row['password']);
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row;
            if($row['id']==5)
             header("Location: yourpage.php");
            else
            header("Location: private.php");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store `id` in `session` then just always check `session`

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])
{
    //retrieve data of user 5 from database 
}
else
{
    //redirect to login page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't compare whether the user is admin or non-admin using `id`, Add a field in your database say `type`, and if the user is `admin` let the `type` be `admin`, if not let it be `user`
2. After user logs in check the `type` field in database for that particular user and redirect according to that.

Considering this is the code for redirect :

```
    if($login_ok)
    {
        unset($row['salt']);
        unset($row['password']);
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row;
        if($row['type'] == "admin"){
           header("Location: private.php");
           die("Redirecting to: private.php");
        }
        else{
            header("Location: otherpage.php");
            die("Redirecting to: private.php");
        }

    }
```

Advantage :

1. If you delete a user or add a new user, it wont affect your coding part.
2. You can have multiple admins, Still you need to check only one condition (no need to check each user ids).

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_SESSION['id']==5)
    header("Location: yourpage.php");
else
    header("Location: private.php");
exit;
```